# Obtener url principal de webView

Tags: android, kotlin, url, webview

Tengo un Webview, funciona perfectamente, ahora necesito obtener la url principal que carga.
Por ejemplo si la pagina que cargo es

```
https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending
```

Deseo Obtener, para mostrarla en un texview

```
https://www.youtube.com
```

Pensaba que era algo sencillo pero al parecer no, además que me he encontrado con un problema adicional, el cual es que la url de la pagina cargada se cambia dependiendo del país o dispositivo desde donde de esta usando la aplicación, por ejemplos si yo cargo `https://www.youtube.com/` se cambia y carga `https://m.youtube.com`/ o también se cambia automaticamente dependiendo de el lenguaje pasa de  `https://example.com` a `https://es.example.com`

Saben si es posible , al parecer creo que si,  ya que por ejemplo en el navegador EDGE al hacer clic en el candado que esta al costado de la url de la pagina cargada, muestra un cuadro y ahí se puede observar la url principal de la pagina en este caso aparece `es.stackoverflow.com`.
Saben si es posible esto?

```
webtest.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient(){
        }

        webtest.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient(){
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun  onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {                 

                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)

                
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)

            
            }
        }


        val setting: WebSettings = webtest.settings
        setting.javaScriptEnabled = true
        setting.domStorageEnabled = true
        webtest.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir de la url

https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending

lo que desea es obtener únicamente esto

https://www.youtube.com

esto es el esquema y el host de la url, lo puedes obtener donde inicia la carga de la url en tu WebView lo cual se realiza dentro de onPageStarted(), convierte a URI tu url y puedes obtener el esquema y el host :

```
  val uri = Uri.parse(url)
  val mydomain = uri.scheme + uri.host
```

Este sería el código dentro de `onPageStarted()` :

```
   override fun  onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {                 
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
             
              val uri = Uri.parse(url)
              val mydomain = uri.scheme + uri.host
                
              println("El dominio a cargar es: $mydomain ")

            }
```